# Drop down links are off to the left?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, hyperlink

can any one see why the drop down links are off to the left?
http://altadorcup.sketchedneo.com/testing/

If you hover on game guides, notice the drop down link box is left instead of middle.

I am unsure which bit of the css is needed so im posting all the drop down menu css

So I want, text aligned left but box's aligned middle if anyone can see the issue?

```
#navigation ul {
    padding:10px 1px 1px 1px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float:middle; text-align:left;
}
#pad{padding:0px 0px 0px 45px;}
#navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;


}

#navigation a{
     display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px 10px;

}


#navigation ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    height:auto;
     z-index:497;
    width:129px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
    line-height:1;
    border:0;
 background:#8c8c8c;
    padding: 2px;  border:1px solid #ffffff;   border-top:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;

}
#navigation ul ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    height:auto;
    width:129px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;

    line-height:1;
    border:0;
 background:#8c8c8c;
    padding: 2px;  border:1px solid #ffffff;   border-top:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
     z-index:497;

}
#navigation li li {
    width:99px;

    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
#navigation li li a {
    padding:4px 10px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
    }
#navigation li ul ul {
    margin:0px 0 0 0px;
    }
#navigation ul li:hover>ul{ opacity: 1; position:absolute; top:99%; left:0; }
#navigation ul ul li:hover>ul{ position:absolute; top:0; left:100%; opacity: 1; z-index:497; background:#8C8C8C; }

    #navigation a:link,#navigation a:visited, #navigation a:active {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align:  left;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `float: middle`. You will need to tweak your absolute positioning.

Comment: In #navigation ul li:hover>ul you'll need to have something like left: 50% instead of left: 0 and margin-left: -65px; (because 65px is about half the width of the drop-down).

Answer (score 0):

They're not. The text in the box is aligned to the left while the text for the menu are aligned in the middle, giving you the impression that the drop down menu is to the left.

Comment: I need the box to align middle.